# How to crop an image edge in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, crop

I need to crop the image edge in the wave shape using Photoshop CS6.
I cannot find any feature like that, tried to use the wave filter but it doesn't work this way.

Any help will be appreciated.
The example is attached.

[image]

Comment: That's likely not an actual macOS screenshot, btw, it's presumably some 3rd party app. macOS screenshots [until Mojave] have a bug where the selected line comes out greyscale not blue.

Answer (score 2):

You can not "crop" an irregular edge. Cropping *always* crops a straight-edged rectangle.

Utilizing **layer masks** would allow for the creation of what appear to be curved sides.

[image]